# Targetting ::selection in jQuery, for an output?

Tags: css, jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm looking at http://jsfiddle.net/duhTB/, which uses CSS to target ::selection.

Now, what I'm trying to do is a little different.  Bear with me.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ywq2x/15/.  I'm trying to make it so that when I highlight text that I have entered into the #id_input-id'd text area and press ctrl+b, the highlighted text is output to the #id_selected-id'd pre block.

If you can see any problems with the code that I am using, can you please indicate them and let me know how I could correct the problems?  If what I'm trying to do isn't possible with jQuery, can you please explain why?  And if there is another way, can you explain it?

Thank you.

For convenience and lasting power, I'll also post the code in question, here:

JS/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#id_input").keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 66 && e.ctrlKey) {    
            var val = $("#id_input::selection").val();
            $("#id_selected").text(val);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>A1:</p>
<textarea rows="2" cols="30" class="txt_input_area dotted" id="id_input">
</textarea>
<div class="now_working">
  <pre id="id_selected"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: "For convenience and lasting power, I'll also post the code in question, here" You are likeable :) Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::selected` selector appears not to work in jQuery but the good news is that there's a [jquery-textrange plugin](https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange) by dwieeb for fetching selected text from input fields and textareas.

Try this :

```
$(function() {
    $("#id_input").on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 66 && e.ctrlKey) {
            e.preventDefault();//inhibit opening Opera's sidebar
        }
    }).on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 66 && e.ctrlKey) {
            var txt = $("#id_input").textrange('get', 'text');
            $("#id_output").text(txt);
        }
    });
});
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywq2x/17/)**

For the record, these are jquery-textrange's full capabilities :

- ('get', 'position'): cursor location in the text field
- ('get', 'start'): starting position of the selected text in the text field
- ('get', 'end'): ending position of the selected text in the text field
- ('get', 'length'): the length of the selected text in the text field
- ('get', 'text'): the text that is selected
- ('set'): select all the text in the field
- ('set', n): selects from the nth character to the end of the text
- ('set', n, length): starting from the nth character, selects `length` characters (or to the end of the text)
- ('set', n, 0): equivalent to ('setcursor', n)
- ('setcursor', n): sets the cursor to the specified position in the text field
- ('replace', 'some text'): replace the selected text, or insert at the cursor location.

*revised 28 Feb 2014 to reflect latest state of the plugin*

With thanks to dwieeb for a plugin that takes the pain out of the most nauseating aspect of web programming - text-ranges.

Comment: So, I've decided to read through the plugin and see how it works.  Any tips before I get started?

Comment: Edit, all I can say is that I admire your hunger for knowledge. I'm generally content to do nothing more than find a plugin that does what I want. Make sure you understand the plugin macroscopically (hopefully a familiar pattern) before you dive into the detail. Then, keep your wits about you and be prepared to run tests to check your understanding as you progress through the code. I expect you will find a major branch within each method to handle IE and all other browsers completely differently. Will be interested to know what you learn.

Comment: @dwieeb, nice plugin. Is my list of methods still correct? Looking at the README.md, it looks like you have made some revisions since Dec '12.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Thanks! Yeah, the only thing that has changed is set() is less sucky. It now uses a starting location and a length (instead of ending location). Details: https://github.com/dwieeb/jquery-textrange/wiki/Set

Comment: @dwieeb, OK, I have revised the list. Are `('replace', ...)`, `('set', ...)` and `('setcursor', ...)` chainable eg `$('#myField').textrange('set', 3, 2).textrange('replace', 'newText').css('color', '#FF0000')`?